# 'The filename, directory name, or volume laber syntax is incorrect' while running Command Prompt script in Context Menu

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, registry, contextmenu

I'm trying to run certain Command Prompt script in context menu. That will be much quicker than opening Command Prompt and type script name and press enter.

So I wrote a Command Prompt script named `ib.cmd` in `C:\CustomExecutables\`.

```
@echo on
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "counter=0"
set "total=0"
set "error=false"

if "%~1"=="" (
  set "target=%cd%"
) else (
  set "target=%~1"
)

echo Target Directory: !target!

for %%F in ( "!target!\*.jpg" "!target!\*.png" "!target!\*.webp" ) do (
  set /a "total+=1"
)

if %total% equ 0 (
  echo No files to process
  pause
  exit /b
)

for %%F in ( "!target!\*.jpg" "!target!\*.png" "!target!\*.webp" ) do (
  set /a "counter+=1"
  title [!counter!/!total!] Processing %%~nxF ...
  echo [!counter!/!total!] Processing %%~nxF ...

  setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
  "E:\PROGRAM\IrfanView\i_view64.exe" "%%~fF" /advancedbatch /convert="%%~dpFconverted\%%~nF.webp"
  endlocal

  if !errorlevel! neq 0 (
    set "error=true"
    echo An error occurred
    pause
    exit /b
  )
)

if !error! equ false (
  title Finished processing !counter! files
  echo Finished processing !counter! files
  exit
)

endlocal
```

If first argument is given, the script will process image files in given directory. If not, it will process files in current working directory.

I've used this script for a while with calling it from Command Prompt, so I don't think there is any error in this script.

Next, I wrote `.reg` file to register that script to context menu.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\background]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\Background\shell]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\Background\shell\QuickTask]
"MUIVerb"="Quick Task"
"Icon"="C:\\Windows\\System32\\shell32.dll,137"
"ExtendedSubCommandsKey"="Directory\\\\ContextMenus\\\\QuickTask"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\ContextMenus]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\ContextMenus\QuickTask]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\ContextMenus\QuickTask\shell]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\ContextMenus\QuickTask\shell\IrfanViewer Convert]
"MUIVerb"="IrfanViewer Batch Convert"
"Icon"="E:\\PROGRAM\\IrfanView\\i_view64.exe"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\ContextMenus\QuickTask\shell\IrfanViewer Convert\command]
@="cmd.exe /K \"C:\\CustomExecutables\\ib.cmd\" \"%V\""
```

But whenever I click 'IrfanViewer Batch Convert', Command Prompt says 'The filename, directory name, or volume laber syntax is incorrect' and don't execute any code of the script.

I even tried to change `@="cmd.exe /K \"C:\\CustomExecutables\\ib.cmd\" \"%V\""` part to `@="cmd.exe /S /K \"C:\\CustomExecutables\\ib.cmd\" \"%V\""` but that didn't changed nothing.

I don't understand why this error happens. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just removed `cmd.exe` part from Registry value.

```
@="\"C:\\CustomExecutables\\ib.cmd\" \"%V\""
```

And it is now working.